# Error sending form on a twitter bootstrap to php mysql using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

Am trying to submit data using modal bootstrap but i can't get it to work. The page will contain more than one modal to enable user to easily update their details.Here the code.

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="overview-modal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Overview</h4>
                        </div>
                        <form  id="overview_form" action="neuro/update_profile.php" class="form-horizontal" >
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Overview</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="overview_input" cols="20" rows="10" name="overview_textarea">

                                        </textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="url"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <div class="btn-group">

                                    <input type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-success" value="Save"/>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the javascript that will handle the form submission to the php file

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $("#save").submit(function () {
                var formData = $("form#overview_form").serialize();
                var my_url = "neuro/update_profile.php";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: my_url,
                    data: formData ,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $("#overview-modal").modal('hide');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error encounted");
                    }
                });

               return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The php  is in a folder called neoro/update_profile ,since i will be using more than one modal in the profile page i have decided to append a url on the form attributes so that it can be easily processed in the php

```
    $profile = new Profile();
$url = $_POST['url'];
if (isset($url)) {
    if ($id == "overview") {

        $overview = $_POST['overview'];
        $profile->save_overview($user_id, $overview);
        return TRUE;
    }
} else {
    header("Location: ./profile.php");
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesnt work... what exactly is happening?

Comment: Failed to submit data to the php script

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$('#overview_form').submit(// your code here);
```

Instead of on `#save`, since you are submitting form not button

Or

Even you can achieve same thing on `#save` but with click function as below

```
 $('#save').click( // here your code );
```

Comment: $('#overview_form').submit(// your code here); did worked

Comment: Yea.. We do that sometimes. And as you are submitting form with Ajax no need to have **action** and **method** attrbs in form tag.

Answer (score 1):

This is full of errors

1. You are sending the form via *GET* method and accessing it via *POST* method
2. Your URL field is empty
3. you are using action field and also submit simultaneously
4. your jquery code is not correct
5. you are using $id variable in your php code which is undefined

Corrected code:

1. `<form  id="overview_form" class="form-horizontal" method="post">`
2. `<input type="hidden" name="url" value='yoururl'/>`

Comment: What do you mean in step 3 ?

Comment: action field of form redirect you to another location where mentioned then jquery or js will not work correctly as you want to stay on same page.